# Display parameters from session of class instance in flask jinja 2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've saved an instance of User called "user_current" into a session variable. Please note, the class has some parameters, such as t_id_user, t_email, etc.

In Flask/Jinja2, how do I reference those parameters for the object embedded in the session variable?

Here's the code below that I used to create the class and instance, and store the instance of that object in a session variable.

Thanks!

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, t_id_user, t_email, t_password, t_security_level, t_name_first, t_name_last, t_enabled, d_visit_first, d_visit_last):
        self.t_id_user = t_id_user
        self.t_email = t_email
        self.t_password = t_password
        self.t_security_level = t_security_level
        self.t_name_first = t_name_first
        self.t_name_last = t_name_last
        self.t_enabled = t_enabled
        self.d_visit_first = d_visit_first
        self.d_visit_last = d_visit_last
        
def usersFillTest():
    t_id_user = "1"
    t_email = "blah@blah.com"
    t_password = "passwordy"
    t_security_level = "5"
    t_name_first = "Testicular"
    t_name_last = "McTesty"
    t_enabled = "True"
    d_visit_first = "2020/09/30"
    d_visit_last = "2020/09/30"
    user_current = User(t_id_user, t_email, t_password, t_security_level, t_name_first, t_name_last, t_enabled, d_visit_first, d_visit_last)
    session["user_current"] = user_current
```

Would it be something like

```
{{ session["user_current"]["t_id_user"] }}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session["user_current"]` contains the object as you create it. Therefore you can access its members like this:

```
{{ session["user_current"].t_id_user }}
```